# Exception code c0000005 in MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel, infinite-loop

So I have a excel macro-enabled sheet (.xlsm) in excel 2010 that pulls in data every 10 seconds through a query that I run in vba. They data is not on a SQL server which is why I am using vba to pull the data. The sheet works fine initially and then it crashes after ~2 hours or so with a popup saying "Microsoft excel has stopped working" and when i click on "problem details", i see the following,

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:                        APPCRASH
  Application Name:                             EXCEL.EXE
  Application Version:                           14.0.6024.1000
  Application Timestamp:                     4d83e39d
  Fault Module Name:                          EXCEL.EXE
  Fault Module Version:                        14.0.6024.1000
  Fault Module Timestamp:                  4d83e39d
  Exception Code:                                  c0000005
  Exception Offset:                                0000000000286885
  OS Version:                                          6.1.7601.2.1.0.18.10
  Locale ID:                                             1033

Additional information about the problem:
  LCID:                                                     1033
  skulcid:                                                 1033
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: updated the question, and no none of them seem to work for me

Comment: What triggers the query to pull in more data? Is it in a loop or does it use "Application.OnTime" or something else?

Comment: Are you pulling in ~20-24 columns of data? 2 hours worth of 10 second intervals would try and push columns off the right end of the worksheet if each new data was inserting itself instead of overwriting the existing data.

Comment: No, all the new data always overwrites the old.